# ZendGdata framework path set error

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

Hello I am using ZendGdata-1.12.5 framework to upload a video on youtube

I used the following in my php code

```
$path = './ZendGdata-1.12.5/library/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

require_once('Zend/Loader.php');  

Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');  
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');  
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');  
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
```

but nothing seems to be working ! help ?

> PHP Warning:  require_once(Zend/Xml/Security.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/youtube_upload_video/ZendGdata-1.12.5/library/Zend/Gdata/App/Base.php
>   on line 30
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'Zend/Xml/Security.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:./ZendGdata-1.12.5/library/')
>   in
>   /var/www/youtube_upload_video/ZendGdata-1.12.5/library/Zend/Gdata/App/Base.php
>   on line 30

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The path is correct, the problem is that Zend Gdata library does not have the Zend/xml folder. It's a small folder with 2 files. All you need to do is following:

1) Go to: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest

2) Download 1.12 (or whatever your version is) MINIMAL package.

3) Extract it on your hard disk.

4) Upload `/library/Zend/Xml` folder to your server's `/ZendGdata-1.12.5/library/` folder so that in your `/ZendGdata-1.12.5/library/Zend` folder you have the `Xml` folder.

5) That's it. Enjoy.

Comment: shamittomar: Great!! I´m using ZendGdata (Youtube API) into cakePHP 2.x as component and I´ve the same problem. Your answer fix my last problem. Thanks.

Comment: As a note, with ZendGdata 1.12.13, I also needed to copy in the Http/Header folder.