# Auto loading zendGdata files & accessing data

Tags: php, blogger, zend-gdata

I am trying to connect my website with my blog on blogger using the zendGdata API and am having 2 issues:

Firstly the Zend_Loader:: functions do not appear to be loading anything and just result in a blank screen. my code so far is as below:

```
require_once('../Includes/ZendGdata-1.12.11/library/Zend/Loader.php'); 
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
```

I am then attempting to connect with:

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'blogger');
$gdClient = new Zend_Gdata($client);
```

But as I say I am getting a blank screen.

For my 2nd query, is the $user and $pass meant to be the email address and client secret generated from the google developer console for my website?

Thanks

Comment: OK I have solved the first part which was that the small xml folder was not included within my library, thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079465/zendgdata-framework-path-set-error.

Comment: P.s I now have the issue with bad authentication, do I use my own user name and password to connect or the email address and client secret generated on the google developer console?